# Google Play Services DriveApi change file parent

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I can't seem to find out how to move file into another folder using Drive.DriveApi from Google Play Services.

Only thing I see is using `driveFolder.createFile(GoogleApiClient, MetadataChangeSet, Contents)` but that's only if I'm going to upload a new file.

`MetadataChangeSet.Builder()` doesn't have any methods that point to file parent.

Is that impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing parents is not currently exposed in the Google Play Services API.  You can fall back to the web RESTful API to do this if you need to: [parents collection](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents).  Just get the resourceId from the DriveId.